# tiny xml null point reference error when deserialize?

Tags: c++

I am working with C++. I have the following XML:

```
<data>
<name> me</name>
<street />
</data>
```

I want to deserialize this xml and i did:

```
TiXMlDocument doc,
tiXmlHandle handle(&doc)
TiXmlElement* sec;
sec=handle.FirstChild("data").FirstChild("name").element;
if (sec)
{ const char* str=sec->GetText();
}
```

And when i write:

```
sec=handle.FirstChild("data").FirstChild("street").element;
if (sec)
{ const char* str=sec->GetText();  //here i have a null reference. pointer error. 
}
```

I need some help with that null pointer pointed out in the code above.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are 'sec' and 'section' the same thing?

Comment: XML is case sensitive - 'Data' and 'data' are different.

Answer (score 1):

Should this:

```
sec=handle.FirstChild("Data").FirstChild("name").element;
if (section)
{ 
    const char* str=section->gettext();
}
```

not be:

```
sec=handle.FirstChild("data").FirstChild("name").element; //you are placing element in the variable sec, so now read the text from sec:
if (sec)
{ 
    const char* str=sec->gettext();
}
```

Comment: yes. you are right! i've edit my code. why do i receive segmentation fault? need some help!